# Calling a c++ .exe from Matlab - Program Stopped Working?

Tags: c++, build, exe, linker-errors

I wrote a code in C++ called FaceTracker.cpp and other code in Matlab that do some analyzes and statics.

What I need to do is adding a button in matlab that calls the FaceTracker when being pressed. I tried to use the following command:

```
 system (['FaceTracker.exe <' nameOfVideo]);
```

but it doesn't work. It opens the FaceTracker.exe GUI, then it stops ! (Like when internet explorer or any other program does sometimes\hang) with the msg "FaceTracker.exe stoped working.

When I tried to run the .exe from command prompt it showed me the following error:

```
  Assertion Faile: Type == IO::TRACKER ... Debug error! R6010 - abort() has been called.
```

---

From what i understd from the answers\ other sites is that I need to statically link libraries.
I read in one site that I need to make the following changes:

```
 The CRT:
 • Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation: Where it reads Runtime   Library, change to Multi-Threaded (/MT).

 The manifest must go:
 • Configuration Properties -> Manifest Tool -> Input and Output: Where it reads Embed Manifest, change to No.
```

But when I do it (Change to /MT) I start getting the following errors:

```
1>  Generating Code... 1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library 1>libcpmtd.lib(xmbtowc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW 1>Tracker.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: void
__thiscall FACETRACKER::Tracker::Load(char const *)" (?Load@Tracker@FACETRACKER@@QAEXPBD@Z) 1>libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW 1>libcpmtd.lib(cout.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
__CrtDbgReportW 1>libcpmtd.lib(cin.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW 1>IO.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW 1>Patch.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW 1>PAW.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW 1>PDM.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW 1>CLM.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW 1>FaceTracker.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW 1>FCheck.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW 1>FDet.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW 1>libcpmtd.lib(cin.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
__free_dbg 1>libcpmtd.lib(xmbtowc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg 1>Tracker.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg 1>libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg 1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg 1>libcpmtd.lib(cout.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
__free_dbg 1>IO.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg 1>Patch.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg 1>PAW.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg 1>PDM.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg 1>CLM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg referenced in function "private: void __thiscall std::_Yarn<char>::_Tidy(void)" (?_Tidy@?$_Yarn@D@std@@AAEXXZ) 1>FaceTracker.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
__free_dbg 1>FCheck.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg 1>FDet.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg 1>libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg referenced in function "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int,struct std::_DebugHeapTag_t const &,char
*,int)" (??2@YAPAXIABU_DebugHeapTag_t@std@@PADH@Z) 1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg 1>libcpmtd.lib(xmbtowc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg 1>libcpmtd.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __calloc_dbg referenced in function __Getctype 1>C:\Users\wew\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\Debug\FaceTracker.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

Any Suggestions?
What do I Have to do in order to be able to use the FaceTracker.exe in every computer, also the ones that doesn't have c++\vs compiler?

besides, why does my program OPENS when I call it from matlab but then Hangs\stops working?
Thank in advance.

Comment: is {InputVid} a string? How would you call the binary from the command line?

Comment: Yes, a string containing a full path... I read on some site that we should compile in "release" not "debug" and that we have to change the "run time library" in the code generation to "multi-threaded". but it didn`t work. when i change to "multi-threaded" it shows me errors.

Answer (score 0):

This almost certainly has nothing to do with debug versus release or whether mt is enabled. You are not making a matlab extension, just using a binary from the command line. If the program works when you type things in from the command line, it should work when called from Matlab unless you are running low on memory (highly unlikely also).

I would examine the contents of . .

```
['FaceTracker.exe < ' InputVid]
```

...and copy and paste the string directly into the command line (system, not Matlab) to see if you can replicate the error. The error is most likely occurring because your exe is not handling the file string well.

Try putting the inputvid, calling m file, and FaceTracker.exe in the working directory to make the most simple scenario. If that works, make things more complex by placing input vid into another directory and bug hunt from there.

Best of luck!

Comment: First of all thanks for answering.
When I run the Facetracker from c++ it runs correctly.
but when I try to run FaceTracker.exe (after copying it to another folder) it showes me the following msg:

Assertiong Faile: Type == IO::TRACKER ...
Debug error!
R6010
- abort() has been called.

Comment: How can I make a FaceTracker.exe file that works on all computers (even the ones which doesn`t have c++\vs compiler) ?!!

Comment: IS your exe dependent on any dll files?

Comment: While there are probably workarounds where you can use Visual Studio to create an app that is not dependent on any DLLs, I find that an easy solution is to use another compiler like DevC++ or Eclipse.  DevC++ will install with a built-in c compiler last time I checked.

Comment: OK, what are your build settings? What frameworks are you using? There must be some dependancies that break when you move the EXE. Does the EXE run if you just fund the one you built using VS and run it in place?

Comment: When I run the .exe from the debug folder it works. but when I try to run it from Matlab (from a matlab file that exists in the same flder - debug) it shows me the following error: Assertiong Faile: Type == IO::TRACKER ... Debug error! R6010 - abort() has been called. And "program stopped working.

Comment: What happens when you compile in release mode out of interest?

Comment: When I try to compile in release mode I got alot of errors that I dont get when I cmpile in debug mode.

Comment: How d I statiscally link libraries in C++?

Comment: What are the errors. Edit your original question and paste in all the errors that happen when you compile in release mode.

Comment: First of all thanks alot for answering. I edited the Question. any suggestions?

Comment: Do what the first error tells you to do . . 
add /NODEFAULTLIB to the linker settings, rebuild and then tell me if there are any new errors

Comment: I changed the code of faceTracker so it doesn`t need input, called it from Matlab. And It WORKED !. the problem is occuring because of the input' I shoulkd send it some other way (it is a string). any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think this exe file depends on some other libraries. You should copy them into one of the directories in your system parameter PATH. Or you can use the static link option when build your project.

Comment: How to do that? (use the static link option)?
I want my .exe file to work on every computer (even the ones that dont have c++\vs compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Your applications don't require the entire Visual C++ compiler to be installed, just the runtime library.  Microsoft has a free redistributable which can add this runtime library to any computer.  You can find vcredist_x86.exe in your Visual C++ install path, or download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328

Comment: Ok but why does FaceTracker.exe Opens when I call it from matlab, starts working but then hangs with the msg: Facetracker.exe stopped workinig, windows is searching for a solution... ??

Comment: You'll need one computer with both MatLab and Visual Studio in order to debug this.  When your program crashes, you'll have the option to start debugging, this lets you debug it when it runs the way Matlab starts it.

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll download it. but what is confusing me that I'v succeeded to call FaceTracker.exe from matlab before, and it worked. but because of a virus I had to format my computer, and now its not working (it works but suddenly stops working). I just cant remember if there is any properties that i Have to change besides what I mentioned on the question.